# How to deactivate onedrive and telemetry in Windows 10 by using a sysprep answer file

Tags: windows, sysprep

We are using the Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB ISO for our company and it does almost all we wanted (no universal apps, no unwanted services, no EDGE, etc).

Unfortunatly, Telemetry is still on and OneDrive activated. I know I could deactivate all of this by GPO but I wonder if it's possible to just include this in a sysprep answer file. Any tried this? That's the two things that are not automated yet.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can't. The fastest way to do this is to use gpedit.msc and deactivate them by GPO. Check under Computer config/admin template/windows component/onedrive.

For telemetry, check under Computer config/admin template/windows component/data collection and preview build and enable telemetry but use the zero parameter.